# Saving Multiple Fragments State

Tags: android, android-fragments

I implemented AppCompatActivity that i used for fragment transaction. Only one AppCompatActivity like:

```
public class UIActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
}
```

The fragment can begin another transaction, leading to having more than one fragment of the same class in the back stack. (illustration)

```
public class UiFragment extends Fragment implements FileChooserListener {
   mybutton.setOnclickListener(){
   // do some stuff, met some condition and add fragment ( of UiFragment), possibly inflating another view, add previous fragment to back stack
   }
}
```

This works fine except that even when i implemented onSaveInstance,on restore instance inflate the firstfragment while other are lost. I want to resume from where the user stopped and being able to access fragment in back stack when the user press the back button.

**IMPLEMENTATION**

*in UIActivity*

```
UIFragment uif;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.push_up_in, R.anim.push_up_out);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ui);


        if (savedInstanceState == null) {


            uif = new UIFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("step", getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("step"));
            bundle.putString(UIFragment.STEP_KEY, getIntent().getExtras().getString(UIFragment.STEP_KEY));

            uif.setArguments(bundle);


            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.content_frame, uif, "myfragment").commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    }


    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState,"myfragment",uif);
    }
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState){
        uif = (UIFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("myfragment");

    }
```

*snippet that adds UIFragment to the stack*

```
public void addNewUIFragment(){
UIFragment uif= new UIFragment ();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    bundle.putSerializable("step", step);
                    bundle.putString(UIFragment.STEP_KEY, sData);
                    uif.setArguments(bundle);

                    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out, R.anim.back_slide_in,
                            R.anim.back_slide_out);
                    transaction.add(R.id.content_frame, uif, "myfragment").commitAllowingStateLoss();
}
```

Comment: can you show more implementation?

Comment: just updated the question with an implementation

Comment: I think you need just .addToBackStack() not .addToBackStack(null)

Comment: addToBackStack() takes a String parameter. An optional name for back stack state, or null.

Comment: You can`t use as parameter null because then fragment not add to backstack.